# Handle socket termination in android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets

I am connected to a device using following code.

Using this socket code I cam perfom all the tasks, but now I need to perform some functions when server is going to be down.  I am not able to find suitable method to do so please help.

**EDIT**

I want to detect when server is disconnected with this client , means after doing transactions server will be disconnected so that i can disable the buttons ,

```
void sendRequest(){

  try {
      this.clientSocket=new Socket("192.168.1.11",2000);
        this.os=new DataOutputStream(this.clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        this.in=new DataInputStream(this.clientSocket.getInputStream());

           sendFirtCommand();   
           Client t=new Client();
        t.start();

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();

        }       
          }// end of the sendRequest
```

My Thread code

```
private class Client extends Thread{
  int time;
  public void run(){
    try{
        while(true){


            //if(in.read()==-1) break;

            int size =in.available();
            if(size>0){

            byte data[]=new byte[size];
            in.readFully(data);
            String str=new String(data);

            // System.out.println(data);
            //char c[]=str.toCharArray();
            str=toHex(data);
            System.out.println(str);
        /*
            if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("050D00E7F0E1000101581D4A1D01FF")){
            System.out.println("Start Left 3"); 

            }

            */

             if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("050d00e7f0e1000101601d4a1d01ff")){
                stopAll();
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        enableAll();
                    }
                });
            }
         }
```

Comment: Can you please edit your post to explain more what you are trying to accomplish?  Is this about detecting if the client did not connect?  Some sort of exception handling issues?

Comment: hello please dont close i realy need its solution

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand.  Are you talking about proper handling of `IOException`s?  That is what the server should get if the client closes the connection.  Make sure you are catching and handling them where appropriate.  Javadocs on the various methods will show you what `Exception`s are thrown and what they mean

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it helps

```
try{
        while(true){
             if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("050d00e7f0e1000101601d4a1d01ff")){
                stopAll();
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        enableAll();
                    }
                });
            }
         }
   }catch(IOException e)
   {
     handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        enableAll();
                    }
                });
   }
```

It seems as if Exception handling is not there in the code you have posted, let me know if i am missing something ...